# Generate Random JSON Strings to insert into the database using JMeter

Tags: database, json, jmeter

I am working on the project in which I need to make a connection to database and insert lot of rows in that Database. I have two columns currently in that database-

```
ID         String PrimaryKey
ACCOUNT    String
```

So I need to insert lot of rows in these two columns with the help of JMeter. I am able to generate `random Unique ID` for ID column by using this-

`${__BeanShell(UUID.randomUUID().toString())}`

But how can I generate a `Random JSON String` for the `ACCOUNT` column?

Or Is there any way I can keep modifying the below JSON String every time whenever I try to insert in the database?

`{"lv":[{"v":{"regId":null,"user":null,"Id":996},"cn":1}],"lmd":1360185}`

Meaning for each thread whenever I am inserting into database, then in the above JSON string something should get modified for each thread and then get inserted in to the database.

Any thoughts how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Why not make a POJO for the JSON string and then with the constructor assign some random values to the properties.  Then just serialize the POJO into JSON and write away.

That way you could write a loop that constructs your object and each construction would make an object that was slightly different than the last one.

Comment: So all these are possible with JMeter? I am new to JMeter. Can you provide me a simple example to achieve my scenario?

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with JMeter. =( I just know it's used in Java environments and would imagine you could make a simple class and use that as part of JMeter.  Look at Jackson (http://jackson.codehaus.org/).  You make a simple Java class, then use Jackson to turn it into JSON.